# Is there a Google Search API I can call, server-side, no strings attached?

Tags: api, backend

I would like to use Google Search to power my site search, without having to use Google-supplied JavaScript or overly-specific (if they need me to say “Powered by Google,” that’s fine).  I don’t want to send users to Google’s domain, and I don’t want them to see a Google Custom Search logo.

Is there an API for this?

Comment: Also curious as to Bing & competing search engines’ support for this kind of service, as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Google AJAX Search API, which can also be used by a server-side application:

http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/documentation/#fonje

The problem with this, however, is that it's limited to 64 results per query, if I remember correctly.

Comment: Your answer was just a minute before Franz’s. Thanks to both of you — the URL you both shared looks exactly right

Answer (score 1):

the normal google search API
 - http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/documentation/#fonje for non javascript (a.k.a. mostly for server side)
 - with the sitesearch parameters

the downsite is, with google custom search you have access to something called on demand index a.k.a. you can create and access a more complete index of your site, with the search api above you have only access to the normal google index, which does not offer on demand index

Comment: Great, thank you! I appreciate the _caveat_, too

Answer (score 0):

There are examples on the google code playground. You can figure out the url its calling using firebug or some similar tool.

Comment: I want to avoid legal grey areas like this. Not to mention, if I am using what amounts to an unofficial or "private API" (to use Apple’s term), it could change at any time, leaving me high & dry.